# Spring and CDI integration with JSF. WebApplicationContext is null

Tags: spring, jsf, cdi

I'm using JSF 2.2, Spring 4.3

I've the following Controller

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped //javax.faces.bean
public class MyController extends SpringAutoDiscoverClass {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionScopedBean}")
    private SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean;

    @Autowired
    private AdvertisingManager advertisingManager;
```

The SpringAutoDiscoverClass is used only to autowire the spring beans.

```
    public abstract class SpringAutoDiscoverClass implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```

and all is working. Now I'm trying to replace the JSF annotations with the CDI annotation. So I've changed the controller in this way

```
@Named
@ViewScoped //javax.faces.view
public class MyController extends SpringAutoDiscoverClass {

    Inject //I've changed also this JSF bean in CDI bean
    private SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean;

    @Autowired
    private AdvertisingManager advertisingManager;
```

but the problem is that inside the postConstruct method of the SpringAutoDiscoverClass the webApplicationContext is null

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
```

In the web.xml all the listeners are correct(all was working with the JSF annotations).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried to switch completely to CDI but all the component that are not annotated don't work. For example the following @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
   .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                        .setScriptEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
   .addScript("classpath:hsql/create_hsql_db.sql")
   .addScript("classpath:hsql/initial_hsql_data.sql")
   .build();
    }